# How to pass an empty string as value of a field in dynamodb dotnet using IAmazonDynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I want to save empty string values to the database & it does not work.

```
{ 
  ...  
  "some_field": ""  
   ...
}
```

I'm using IAmazonDynamoDB & UpdateItemAsync method.
How can I perform that?

Comment: What is the code how you save the values? Why do you want to store empty values?

Comment: Because of logic in my app, null is null, empty strings are empty strings "", and my UI particular Angular according to different values null or empty string provides different view for the end-user.

Comment: I have found the by my self solution IsEmptyStringValueEnabled = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the by my self solution - configuration field **IsEmptyStringValueEnabled = true** in **DynamoDBContextConfig** class.